# Conditions are not working properly in __init__

Tags: python, class, if-statement, pygame, boolean

What I'm trying to do here is to start game either in window mode or in fullscreen.

```py
    def __init__(self, fsc):
        pygame.init()

        self.fullscreen = fsc
        print(self.fullscreen)

        if self.fullscreen:
            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        elif not self.fullscreen:
            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_WIDTH))

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        #self.font = pygame.font.Font('Arial', 32)
        self.running = True
```

If I try to print the `self.fullscreen`, it will print either `True` or `False`. However the conditions are ignoring it, and the game starts in the fullscreen mode anyway, even if the `self.fullscreen` is `False`.

Comment: Is it really the boolean `False`, or the string `"False"`? `"False"` (the string) is not empty, so it's `True` in boolean context. We can't know as you didn't show how you call this piece of code. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @ThierryLathuille oh yeah, I forgot that in the previous file I have `f"{fsc}"` instead of `fsc`.. Sorry, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in the other file, I accidentally made the variable a string:

```py
# I had
player_info = [f'{nickname}', f'{gender}', f'{fullscreen}']
# Instead of
player_info = [f'{nickname}', f'{gender}', fullscreen]
```

Making the `fsc = player_info[2]` a string instead of boolen.

Answer (score 0):

try to get rid of the elif and use just else

```
if self.fullscreen:
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
else:
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_WIDTH))
```

Comment: It wasn't a problem of conditions, I just forgot to make the variable actually a boolean

Comment: @Martinko366 but that if statement is really strange. A simple if else (like suggests Kawamatzu) is a better option.

Comment: @SimoX I have other variables there and different conditions, so I actually need it that way, I just sent an important part of the code here that I found out was faulty